# Display a child to outside its offscreen parent until parent appears wide enough

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a horizontally sliding menu that toggles between being aligned to, and hidden beyond, the left-hand side of the browser window:

```
Open (has class "open")     Closed (class "open" removed)
+------+--------------+     +---------------------+
|      |              |     |                     |
|      |              |     |                     |
|      |              |     |                     |
|      |              |     |                     |
|      |              |     |                     |
+------+--------------+     +---------------------+
```

SCSS:

```
header nav[role="navigation"] {
    background: $primary-colour;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -282px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 282px;
    @include transition(left 250ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000));
    &.open {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Now let's say I want a toggle button that either: 1) sits at the left of the window while the menu is closed, and 2) sits inside the menu, aligned to the right when it is open:

```
Open                        Closed
+--+---+--------------+     +---+-----------------+
|  | x |              |     | = |                 |
|  +---+              |     +---+                 |
|      |              |     |                     |
|      |              |     |                     |
|      |              |     |                     |
+------+--------------+     +---------------------+
```

In addition, it should honour the menu's transition, so that it aligns itself to the right-hand side at exactly the point at which the menu's visible width matches the width of the button. Is there a way to achieve this with CSS alone?

Comment: Could you create a transition for the icon (with a delay + timing to match the menu's transition timing) and have it applied when its parent (the menu) has class open?

Comment: @zgood I _could_, but there's easing on the menu's transition which means doing some horrible maths to try and figure out exactly how the corresponding easing should be on the button... It'd be fine if they were both set in motion at the same time, but there'll be a delay until the menu is as wide as the button, at which point the button will shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little CSS jiggling, I came up with a solution:

```js
// Some JS to illustrate the animation
$('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.nav').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.window {
  background: lightgrey;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
.nav {
  background: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 250ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: width 250ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  -ms-transition: width 250ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  -o-transition: width 250ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition: width 250ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
}
.nav.open {
  width: 80px;
}
.nav-toggle-wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-toggle {
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="window">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-toggle-wrapper">
      <div class="nav-toggle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, see an example on jsfiddle > [link](https://jsfiddle.net/verism/94eL76ac/3/)